# Can Granger causality be used in average values?

Tags: regression, time-series, causality, granger-causality

I have gene expression data for several genes in different time points (but I guess the type of data doesn't make any difference for this question). I would like to use Granger causality to see if changes in expression in one gene could be related to changes in another. However, the individuals in each time point are different. Therefore, I cannot pair an observation in t with one in t+1. I thought about using the average gene expressions for each gene in each time point, in order to circumvent this pairing problem, but someone told me that that wouldn't be correct. That might be so, but I still don't get exactly why. Many examples of Granger causality I see are not exactly paired. Does it, or does it not, make sense to use Granger causality in averages?

Comment: Could you offer some examples which are not paired? I am just curious to learn some.

Comment: @RichardHardy just to be clear, when I said "not exactly paired" I meant not paired by individuals or another more precise pairing unit. Take [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00704-010-0342-3) article for example. Global average temperature was the pairing method. It was not paired by measurement stations, for example. We don't even know if the measurement stations were the same.

Comment: @RichardHardy Or the classic and funny chicken and egg [article](http://www.walkerd.people.cofc.edu/400/Sobel/P-12.%20Thurman%20-%20Chickens%20Eggs%20and%20Causality.pdf), that I see in many tutorials on Granger. The number of chickens and egg production in the USA is basically a sum. The chickens and the eggs are not the same. And, for me, a sum is as good as an average.

Comment: @RichardHardy I see that you are in financial econometrics. Can't you use Granger, for example, to try to see causality between overnight interest rate and average spread from banks, or average value of bank stocks, or even average dividend yield from bank stocks? If you take a long period of time, the stocks might even belong to different banks, because some might go bankrupt, and others might open their capital. But, it seems to me, that some temporal relationship could be captured even with these averages. And it seems the same for me for gene expression. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Makes sense. It basically depends on how you define the object of interest. If the object is the average (like interest rates, stock indices etc.), it can be taken as a primitive and then Granger causality applies directly. I cannot tell whether it makes sense to define the object of interest as an average in gene expression data, as I am not a biologist/geneticist.

Comment: @RichardHardy thanks. I don't see any reason why gene expression would be different. It's not fundamentaly different from other quantitative variables for which Granger was developed.

Comment: I think this is a subject-matter rather than statistical question. Technically, there is nothing to prevent using an average, but it has to make sense from the subject-matter perspective. That is all.